# Problems implementing a binary tree

Tags: python, syntax-error, binary-tree

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.l = None
        self.r = None
        self.v = v

class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def put(self, v):
        if self.root is None:
            self.root = Node(v)
        else:
            if self.root is None:
                self.root = Node(v)
            elif self.root.v <= v:
                self.root.r = self.put(self.root.r, v)
            elif self.root.v > v:
                self.root.l = self.put(self.root.l, v)
        return self.root

    def __contains__(self, v):
        return finns(self.root, v)

    def write(self):
        if self.root is not None:
            print(self.root.v)
            if self.root.l is not None:
                self.write(self.root.l)
            if self.root.r is not None:
                self.write(self.root.r)

a = BinaryTree()
a.put(3)
a.put(4)
a.write()
```

I wonder why it doesn't work. It says:

```
TypeError: put() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I just want to use `put()` to input integers in the tree.

(Note: "V" stands for value. "R" for right and "L" for left.)

Comment: You call `self.put` with two arguments, `self.root.r` and `v`. That's one too many argument.

Comment: Remove the `self` before `put` to call it from another object.

Comment: You write `self.put(self.root.r, v)`. Here you feed two parameters explicitly (and a third is the `self`). But your `put` only expects two (implicitly) and one (explicitly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the `TypeError` because you're using `put()` incorrectly. However the real problem is you're not building the tree properly.

In the code below that problem is fixed plus I also corrected the `write()` `__contains__()` methods both of which also had.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.l = None
        self.r = None
        self.v = v

class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def put(self, v):
        if self.root:
            self._put(v, self.root)
        else:
            self.root = Node(v)

    def _put(self, v, node):
        if v < node.v:
            if node.l:
                self._put(v, node.l)
            else:
                node.l = Node(v)
        else:
            if node.r:
                self._put(v, node.r)
            else:
                node.r = Node(v)

    def __contains__(self, v):
        return (False if not self.root
                    else self._find(v, self.root) is not None)

    def _find(self, v, node):
        if v == node.v:
            return node
        elif v < node.v and node.l is not None:
            return self._find(v, node.l)
        elif v > node.v and node.r is not None:
            return self._find(v, node.r)

    def write(self):
        if self.root is not None:
            self._write(self.root, 0)

    def _write(self, node, level):
        if node is not None:
            self._write(node.l, level+1)
            print('  '*level + str(node.v))
            self._write(node.r, level+1)

a = BinaryTree()
a.put(3)
a.put(4)
a.put(5)
a.put(9)
a.put(7)
a.put(10)
a.write()
print('')
print('{:2} in "a" -> {}'.format(5, 5 in a))
print('{:2} in "a" -> {}'.format(42, 42 in a))
```

Output:

```
3
  4
    5
        7
      9
        10

 5 in "a" -> True
42 in "a" -> False
```

Comment: Yes, I see the changes. The nodes are not linked with each others to form a tree, once I put more integers, they replace each others rather than add up to a tree. Could you refer me to a Python study that helps me fix this issue? And thanks!

Comment: When an attempt is made to add a Node with the same value as an existing one, it will replace it. This is because the `if self.root.v <= v:` will be `True` when the two values are compared. Other than that, I'm not sure what you mean about them not adding up to a tree. I don't know of any Python-specific resources, but the subject of binary trees is widely written about which I'm sure you can find yourself—they should prove helpful even if the examples they contain are written in another computer language.

Comment: Okey Sir, I will try to explain myself. In the code above we can put 2 integers and the algoritm will seperate them to its values on each corner of the tree. When we add up more integers, they will only replace each other either on the left or right side when our input is bigger or smaller then what we put in the beginning. You can try it when you add up for instance:
'a.put(5)'
'a.put(9)'
'a.put(10)'
'a.put(1)'
When you run the code, the algo will print:
3
1
10
It replaced 4 on the left corner with ---> 1 and on the right it added 10. I wanted to build it up as a tree with all input

Answer (score 0):

In the line `self.root.r = self.put(self.root.r, v)` you call the instance method `put` with two explicit arguments. Since you are calling the method on `self`, the method is bound and `self` is passed implicitly as the first argument (for three arguments total).

Your code doesn't currently make enough sense for me to offer an easy fix. For example, you could pass an instance explicitly to `BinaryTree.put`, but you're currently trying to pass an instance of `Node` not `BinaryTree`.

Comment: Yea, I think I see that. I am trying to link the nodes togehter now. Thanks for the help.